# How do I keep PC awake after scheduled task runs?

Tags: windows, power-management, windows-task-scheduler

I have a PC that I access via remote desktop, during specific hours of specific days of the week. It's inconvenient to get to physically, so I want it to wake up on its own and stay awake during those hours, but be able to sleep any other time. I neither need nor want it to "wake on LAN" (mainly because **a)** I don't want it waking up every time I just open a Windows Explorer window, and **b)** I have found the "wake on LAN" feature to be finicky and unreliable).

To solve this goal, I have used the `powercfg` commands via Task Scheduler, as seen in [the answer to this question](https://superuser.com/questions/942684/is-it-possible-to-apply-a-time-frame-to-windows-7-power-settings). This *almost* works; the tasks do in fact correctly change the power scheme as desired. But, the computer goes right back to sleep two minutes later, after waking up to select the "High Performance" scheme, even though that scheme specifically disables sleeping.

What Windows setting do I need to change to get the computer to stay awake after the task runs and sets the "High Performance" scheme as the active power plan?

Comment: @WasifHasan: thanks for your proposed edit. However, please note that this question is not _about_ the tags you suggested ([tag:networking] and [tag:wake-on-lan]). Indeed, the question is specifically _not_ about those things; I mention them only incidentally to explain why my question wouldn't be answered by applying those technologies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows actually has a second, hidden setting that controls sleep behavior. It's used whenever the computer wakes up for some reason other than the user explicitly doing so, such as when a scheduled task has been configured to wake the computer when it runs. The default value for this setting is `2 Minutes`.

This setting can be changed in the "Power Options" dialog, but only after it's been unhidden. You can accomplish this with this command:

`powercfg -attributes SUB_SLEEP 7bc4a2f9-d8fc-4469-b07b-33eb785aaca0 -ATTRIB_HIDE`

This tells `powercfg` to *remove* the `ATTRIB_HIDE` attribute from the ["Sleep unattended sleep timeout"](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/customize/power-settings/sleep-settings-sleep-unattended-idle-timeout) setting found under the "Sleep" subsection of the settings. That setting's GUID is `7bc4a2f9-d8fc-4469-b07b-33eb785aaca0`. Once you've run that command in a command prompt window, the next time you open the "Power Options" dialog, you'll see this setting available:

[image: Power Options dialog]

Just change the value to whatever you like, i.e. something long enough to keep the computer awake as long as you want it to stay awake after waking up to run a schedule task. Set the value to `0 Minutes` to disable the timeout completely; this will allow the computer to follow whatever the power plan's regular "Sleep after" setting is.

If you ever want to hide the option again, just restore the `ATTRIB_HIDE` value to the setting:

`powercfg -attributes SUB_SLEEP 7bc4a2f9-d8fc-4469-b07b-33eb785aaca0 +ATTRIB_HIDE`

Comment: Didn't work for me at beginning. Here's how to find all possible hidden power settings: https://superuser.com/questions/1437851/how-to-access-hidden-power-and-processor-options-in-windows-10

Anyway after running "powercfg -attributes _SUB-GROUP_ _UNATTENDSLEEP_ -ATTRIB_HIDE" and even rebooting nothing changed. Then visited "https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/87782-change-system-unattended-sleep-timeout-windows-10-a.html" and found this "powercfg /SETDCVALUEINDEX SCHEME_CURRENT 238C9FA8-0AAD-41ED-83F4-97BE242C8F20 7bc4a2f9-d8fc-4469-b07b-33eb785aaca0 120". Now the setting appeared! Cool :-)

Answer (score 2):

There is **only one correct way** of doing this. One NEVER changes settings.

Runs a program preventing sleeping or the display turning off while the program runs. Doesn't affect the screensaver.

For more info see docs https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-setthreadexecutionstate

NOTE: Do not use the constant

`ES_USER_PRESENT` as it will always fail.

From above link

**To Use**

```
KeepDisplayOn <commandline of program to run>

KeepSystemOn <commandline of program to run>
```

---

```
@Echo Off

ECHO Three files follow

ECHO PreventSleep.bat

ECHO.

ECHO This file compiles KeepDisplayOn.vb and KeepSystemOn.vb to KeepDisplayOn.exe and KeepSystemOn.exe using the system VB.NET compiler.

ECHO.

ECHO Runs a program preventing sleeping or the display turning off while the program runs

ECHO.

ECHO To Use

ECHO      KeepDisplayOn ^<commandline of program to run^>

ECHO      KeepSystemOn ^<commandline of program to run^>

ECHO.

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\vbc "%~dp0\KeepDisplayOn.vb" /out:"%~dp0\KeepDisplayOn.exe" /target:winexe

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\vbc "%~dp0\KeepSystemOn.vb" /out:"%~dp0\KeepSystemOn.exe" /target:winexe

pause
```

---

```
'KeepSystemOn.vb

imports System.Runtime.InteropServices 



Public Module MyApplication  



Public Declare UNICODE Function SetThreadExecutionState Lib "Kernel32" (ByVal esFlags as Integer) as Integer

Public Const  ES_AWAYMODE_REQUIRED = &h40

Public Const  ES_CONTINUOUS = &h80000000

Public Const  ES_DISPLAY_REQUIRED = &h2

Public Const  ES_SYSTEM_REQUIRED = &h1

Public Const  ES_USER_PRESENT = &h4





    Public Sub Main ()

        Dim wshshell as Object

        Dim Ret as Integer

        WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

        Ret = SetThreadExecutionState(ES_Continuous + ES_System_Required + ES_Awaymode_Required)

        WshShell.Run(Command(), , True)

    End Sub 

End Module
```

---

```
'KeepDisplayOn.vb

imports System.Runtime.InteropServices 



Public Module MyApplication  



Public Declare UNICODE Function SetThreadExecutionState Lib "Kernel32" (ByVal esFlags as Integer) as Integer

Public Const  ES_AWAYMODE_REQUIRED = &h40

Public Const  ES_CONTINUOUS = &h80000000

Public Const  ES_DISPLAY_REQUIRED = &h2

Public Const  ES_SYSTEM_REQUIRED = &h1

Public Const  ES_USER_PRESENT = &h4





    Public Sub Main ()

        Dim wshshell as Object

        Dim Ret as Integer

        WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

        Ret = SetThreadExecutionState(ES_Continuous + ES_Display_Required + ES_Awaymode_Required)

        WshShell.Run(Command(), , True)

    End Sub 

End Module
```

---

Posted to my repository as well https://winsourcecode.blogspot.com/2020/05/keepdisplayon-runs-program-preventing.html